# Display a list from controller method viewbag to a list in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have following GET method in my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetLinesByDestination()
{ 
    destinationService = new DestinationService();
    ViewBag.Destination_id = new SelectList(destinationService.All(), "Destination_id", "city");

    lineService = new LineService();
    ViewBag.Lines = new SelectList(lineService.All(), "line_id", "arrival");
    return View();
}
```

POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetLinesByDestination(int? Destination_id)
{
    destinationService = new DestinationService();
    ViewBag.Destination_id = new SelectList(destinationService.All(), "Destination_id", "city", Destination_id);

    lineService = new LineService();
    ViewBag.Lines = new SelectList(lineService.GetLinesByDestination(Convert.ToInt16(Destination_id)), "line_id", "arrival").ToList();

    return View();
}
```

View code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Destinations", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Destination_id", null, "- Select a destination you want to depart from -", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form -control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Destination_id", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Lines", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownList("Lines", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Lines", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

All this does when executing the GET is retrieve a list of all destinations and all lines in my database. However, when clicking 'submit' and so the POST method is executed, only the lines that depart from the by the user selected destination should be shown. This is fully functional.

Now my actual question:

The Destination_id ViewBag should remain a dropdownlist in the view, since the user has to pick an option from here. I'd however like the Lines shown as a list (like < li >) on the view, so not a dropdownlist. How do I do this? I have tried some foreach loops earlier but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Iterating Through Your SelectList**

You should be able to just iterate through your ViewBag collection as expected by referring to the `Text` and `Value` properties set when binding to your `SelectList`:

```
@if (ViewBag.Lines != null) {
    <ul>
        @foreach (var line in ViewBag.Lines){
            <li>
               @line.Text - @line.Value
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

For ease of use, you might consider actually binding this collection to a specific class instead of a `SelectList`, which would not only give you strong typing within your View, but it would allow you to include / reference properties besides just `Text` and `Value`.

**Binding Your Values**

As far as actually posting values that were "selected", you would likely want to consider outputting a checkbox value for each list item and then store properties related to that item, which could be posted to your form:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var line in ViewBag.Lines){
        <li>
           @line.Text - @line.Value
           <input type='checkbox' name='lines[]' value='@line.Value' / >
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

This would assume that you would want to post back an array of values that represented the "value" of each of the lines that were selected. Likewise, if you wanted to only include a single option, you could replace these with radio buttons and ensure that the `name` attribute properly binds to your `destination_id` property:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var line in ViewBag.Lines){
        <li>
           @line.Text - @line.Value
           <input type='radio' name='Destination_id' value='@line.Value' / >
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, you have been very helpful! Can i ask you one little more question, I do indeed get a list now as seen on this picture: http://imgur.com/a/ZjBJF I know I included both Line_id and arrival in my viewbag, in my database these both are integers aswell, so it makes sense. How do I retrieve the string value of those though, just like with city in my Destination_id viewbag (city is a string obviously)? That would be a nice extra, being able to make that conversion/lookup?

Comment: You _could_ use LINQ to handle this (e.g. `@(ViewBag.Destinations.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Value == 42)?.Text` or something like that, but otherwise things will be a bit nasty (as that doesn't belong in your View).

This is really where you would likely want to consider using a proper ViewModel instead and storing all of this in a single model as opposed to a ViewBag. If you did that you could store this content within a Dictionary that would allow you to easily access any of your properties based on a value / index, etc.

Comment: Yes, I think using a VM will be more interesting aswell. I'll try that later on. I've also thought about another solution: I have a DAO and service layer. Can't I use LINQ in these layers and call the method in my controller, something like this: `return db.Line where(l => l.Line_id==Line_id)` and then put the whole Line in the list somehow? Just to get an idea though, I know it's not the right syntax.